# Using ref functions with Flow -- property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm adding Flow to an existing project. My normal prop type checks are working great, but I can't figure out why there are issues with my search input ref function. I have followed the Flow documentation and set up a line with `searchInput: ?HTMLInputElement`, but that just causes more errors. Here's a stripped down version of the code I'm using, with all relevant `this.searchInput` references remaining:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class DataTable extends Component {

    searchInput: ?HTMLInputElement

    loadNextPage = () => {
        const isFetching = this.props.isFetching
        const number = this.props.paginationNumber
        const links = this.props.links
        if (!isFetching && links.next && this.searchInput.value === '') {
            this.props.fetchData(number + 1, 10)
        }
    }
    handleKeyDown = e => {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            this.search(e.target.value)
        }
    }
    search = text => {
        this.props.searchData(1, 1, text)
        this.forceUpdate()
    }
    handleSearch = () => {
        this.search(this.searchInput.value)
    }
    handleClear = () => {
        this.clearSearch()
    }
    clearSearch = () => {
        const number = this.props.paginationNumber
        if (this.searchInput.value !== '') {
            this.searchInput.value = ''
            this.props.clearSearch()
            this.props.fetchData(number + 1, 10)
        }
    }

    render() {
            <Flex justify="center">
            <Box>
                <input
                type="search"
                ref={ input => this.searchInput = input }
                onKeyDown={ this.handleKeyDown }
                />
                <PrimaryButton
                onClick={ this.handleSearch }>
                SEARCH
                </PrimaryButton>
                <PrimaryButton 
                onClick={ this.handleClear }>
                CLEAR
                </PrimaryButton>
            </Box>
            </Flex>
        )
    }
```

This produces the following error for every reference to `this.searchInput.value`:

```
this.search(this.searchInput.value)
^^^^^ property `value`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
this.search(this.searchInput.value)
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null or undefined
```

I also tried removing the `?` from `?HTMLInputElement` but that gives me this error:

```
ref={ input => this.searchInput = input }
^^^^^ null. This type is incompatible with
ref={ input => this.searchInput = input }
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ HTMLInputElement
```

Any ideas how I can get these type checks to pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're attempting to access `value` on something that is typed as maybe there. The reason is right on that same page:

> The `?` in `?HTMLButtonElement` is important. In the example above the
>   first argument to `ref` will be `HTMLButtonElement | null` as React will
>   call your `ref` callback with null when the component unmounts. Also,
>   the `button` property on `MyComponent` will not be set until React has
>   finished rendering. Until then your `button` ref will be undefined.
>   Protect yourself against these cases and use a `?` (like in
>   `?HTMLButtonElement`) to protect yourself from bugs.

It seems like overkill, but can definitely save you from random issues. You should make the following changes:

```
class DataTable extends Component {
  searchInput: ?HTMLInputElement

  loadNextPage = () => {
      const isFetching = this.props.isFetching
      const number = this.props.paginationNumber
      const links = this.props.links
      if (!isFetching && links.next && this.searchInput && this.searchInput.value === '') {
          this.props.fetchData(number + 1, 10)
      }
  }

  handleSearch = () => {
    if (!this.searchInput) {
      return
    }

    this.search(this.searchInput.value)
  }

  clearSearch = () => {
    const number = this.props.paginationNumber;
    if (this.searchInput && this.searchInput.value !== '') {
      this.searchInput.value = ''
      this.props.clearSearch()
      this.props.fetchData(number + 1, 10)
    }
  }

  // ...etc
}
```

You're trying to access a property on something typed as being possibly `null`, which is why you're seeing the error. You just need to check for existence.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarantee why this happens, but I think it is because ref is because flow is being executed before the ref callback is being called, hence on the first render/mount the ref is equal to null.

One way to solve this would be to put:

```
searchInput: any
```

This is not the best solution, because you aren't exactly specifying a type, but you can also try doing something like

```
searchInput: HTMLInputElement | null
```

Cant guarantee the second approach will work for you. Sometimes I find it inevitable to use **any** type, just to save myself a lot of time. I strongly suggest to avoid it as much as possible though...